# Is there a way to quickly assign vertex groups?

Tags: scripting, vertex-groups

i have a plane with 1024 different faces on it. i am attempting to set each 1 of these faces to a different vertex group is there a way to do this via script?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is.  This script requires that you've already made the grid your active object:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# Get a mesh from an object and make it a bmesh
object = bpy.context.object

if object and object.type == 'MESH':

    # Create a bmesh from the object
    if object.mode == 'OBJECT':
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(object.data)
    else:
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(object.data)
        
    # Validate bmesh data structures
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    deform_layer = bm.verts.layers.deform.verify()

    # process each face in the bmesh
    for i, face in enumerate(bm.faces):
        group = object.vertex_groups.new(name=f'GRP_{i:02}')
        # Assign each vertex in the face to the face's vertex group
        for vert in face.verts:
            vert[deform_layer][group.index] = 1.0

    # update the object's mesh from the bmesh
    if object.mode == 'OBJECT':
        bm.to_mesh(object.data)
        bm.free()
    else:
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(object.data)
```

replace `object = bpy.context.object` with whatever means of selecting the object you want to do this with.

Also, replace `GRP_` with whatever prefix you want your groups to have and the `2` in `{i:02}` with how many digits you want. For 1024 faces, I would use `4` so that the groups will appear in numeric sort order.

This script

- creates a bmesh from the active object, if there is an active object and it is a mesh object.
- validates three data structures, the verts and faces lookup tables and the deform layer, where the vertex group information is stored in a bmesh
- For every face it creates a new vertex group and adds each of the vertices from that face to the group.
- finally it copies the bmesh to the object's mesh data.

## A suggestion of how to sort the faces in order

The problem is that because a mesh with many faces was probably created as a simple mesh and then subdivided, the faces don't have a particular order, nor do the vertices.  Here's a simple mesh showing the vertex indices.

[image: Simple mesh]

You do have the advantage that the mesh is all quads, so the outline of the algorithm is fairly simple:

- Find the upper left corner, for whatever orientation you want.  Here it's vertex '3'.
- Find the face that contains that vertex.
- Create the face-based vertex group and fill it out with the four vertices
- Pick one of the two vertices attached to 3 by an edge, either 9 or 12 in the example.  Remember the other one.
- Find the face containing the new vertex, say 9.
- Repeat the process above until you've finished the row.
- Start over with the vertex you  remembered and do it again.
- Continue repeating rows until there aren't any left.

Comment: i see thank you tho this sets every vertex to its own vertex group in looking to set every face to its own.

Comment: Doh.  Give me a few minutes.  The faces code is similar, but requires one more loop.

Comment: sorry to ask. but if possible i also noticed that it dose not do consecutive faces so it will put vertex group 1 & 2 on either sides of the object, is there a way to make then be next to each other?